Cannot read syscall arguments from a kprobe handler
I'm installing a kprobe on sys_kill and I want to monitor PIDs and signal numbers.
While I can install the kprobe and get some data in dmesg, the data looks wrong and I cannot make sense of it.
Below is the code that I have:
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>

static struct kprobe kp;


static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    pid_t pid = (pid_t)regs->di;
    int sig = (int)regs->si; 

    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: %d, Signal: %d\n", pid, sig);

    return 0;
}

static void handler_post(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long flags)
{
    pid_t pid = (pid_t)regs->di;
    int sig = (int)regs->si;  

    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: %d, Signal: %d\n", pid, sig);
}


static int __init kprobe_init(void)
{
    kp.symbol_name = "__x64_sys_kill";
    kp.pre_handler = handler_pre;
    kp.post_handler = handler_post;

    int ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "register_kprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe registered for __x64_sys_kill\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit kprobe_exit(void)
{
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe unregistered\n");
}

module_init(kprobe_init)
module_exit(kprobe_exit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

It gives me the following output:
kernel: [ 2605.007657] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007658] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007660] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007661] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007662] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007663] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007666] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007667] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007668] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007669] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007671] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007672] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007674] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007675] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007676] kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62
kernel: [ 2605.007677] kprobe post_handler: kill syscall - PID: 6029144, Signal: 62

I tried different approaches:

I tried kretprobes, got the same result
I tried to check the ax value to make sure it is the kill system call by checking ax agains __NR_kill, but it never got past the if condition.

    long syscall_nr = regs->orig_ax;

    // Check if it is the kill syscall (syscall number 62 on x86_64)
    if (syscall_nr == __NR_kill) {
        // NEVER GOT HERE
    }
}

So I thought I ask for help here. I do not do this as part of a project, my goal is to learn kernel programming and Linux kernel internals.

Syscall wrappers (__x64_sys_xxx) created by the standard SYSCALL_DEFINEn(...) macros only take a single argument: a pointer to a struct pt_regs holding the user registers. See also this other answer of mine where I explain this.
Your kprobe handlers get the kernel pt_regs, but you want the user pt_regs so you need to dereference regs->di to get ahold of it:
static int handler_pre(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct pt_regs *user_regs = (struct pt_regs *)regs->di;
    pid_t pid = (pid_t)user_regs->di;
    int sig = (int)user_regs->si; 

    printk(KERN_INFO "kprobe pre_handler: kill syscall - PID: %d, Signal: %d\n", pid, sig);

    return 0;
}


Perfect, thanks very much.

Is this the case in older kernels? For example 4.4 and lower?

@Jelal more or less yes, but it depends. Not all syscalls use those macros and not all archs have the same macros defined. YMMV.

It seems that You need to use copy_from_user on the argument

@flav I'm not sure I follow. Both regs and user_regs are kernel-allocated structures so no copy_from_user needed. The values in user_regs are just values and not pointers so again no copy_from_user is needed.

@MarcoBonelli It seems that user_regs are in user space ; When I try to get it ; I obtain a crash kernel : but with r = copy_from_user(&statxbuf, (struct statx *)user_regs->r8, sizeof (struct statx)); is ok

@flav user_regs are definitely not in userspace, otherwise your code would crash anyway because you are doing user_regs->r8 before copy_from_user() is invoked. It's what the user register is pointing to that is in userspace. That makes snse, it's a syscall that takes a pointer to a struct as parameter. In my example above it's just a value in the register ->si so no copy_from_user() is needed, but in your case you need it.
