how to get sys call params in krobe pre_handler in x86
I tried to use krpobe to hook __x64_sys_mount
struct kprobe mount_kprobe = {
    .symbol_name = "__x64_sys_mount",
    .pre_handler = mount_kprobe_pre_handler,
    .post_handler = mount_kprobe_post_handler,
};

and inside the mount_kprobe_pre_handler, i tried to get mount params via
static int mount_kprobe_pre_handler(struct kprobe *p, struct pt_regs *regs){
    printk(KERN_INFO, "dev_name : %s", regs->di); 
}

but the values show is not what i mount
whats wrong ?

I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78668467/cannot-read-syscall-arguments-from-a-kprobe-handler
